# I need to add/remove columns and rows with a couple of spin buttons

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with a sheet that has a few places to input parameters (number of samples, number of measurements, part number, etc.), and a button that will create a data sheet based on the inputs.  I have set up the macro to also add a couple of spin buttons to add/remove # of samples and add/remove # of measurements.

I have the spin buttons linked to the cells I would like to change, but I need some code that will check to see if that value changes (i.e. the user would like to add/remove a column or a row).  I tried doing a loop, but that failed miserably and ended in me losing a half hour of code with a crash.  I'm new to vba, and I would love to get this macro finished.

The other option I could do is use 4 buttons with individual macros, but I would need to be able to jump  from that macro, to a specific part of another macro.  Is that possible?

Thank you!

EDIT: here is the code I have written from the answer I received, but I am getting the error: "Object variable or with block variable not set".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim del As Boolean

If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("K1"))) Is Nothing Then
    If Cells(1, 11) > samples Then
        samples = Cells(1, 11)
        Application.Run ("samplechange")
    ElseIf Cells(1, 11) < samples Then
        del = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Are you sure you want to delete a sample column?      Enter True/False.", Title:="delete?", Type:=4)
        If del = True Then
            samples = Cells(1, 11)
            Application.Run ("samplechange")
        ElseIf del = False Then
            Cells(1, 11) = samples
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run code when a cell changes, in your VB editor/Macro editor double click the sheet on which the cell resides, then using the drop downs at the top code editing area choosed `Worksheet` and `Change`. This will create a new subroutine in the code area that looks like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

`Target` is the range that changed. You can test to see if this is the range/cell you care about with something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Not(Intersect(target, Range("MyRangeToTest")) Is Nothing) Then
          'Your cell was changed, so do something here
     End if
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I saw this method in my searching, but it didn't look like it applied to what I was trying to do.  Thank you for clarifying.  Regarding the second part of my question, is there a way to jump to a label in another macro?

Comment: No you can't jump to a label inside another subroutine or function. Instead, take code out of the label and stick it in it's own subroutine (passing parameters to it if needed) and then call that subroutine from both chunks of code that need it.

Comment: Thanks! Here is the code I have written, but it's giving me an error: "Object variable or with block variable not set".

EDIT: adding code to original post

Comment: My fault. Should be `If Not(Intersect(range1, range2)) IS NOTHING) then`  Misplaced a parantheses. See if that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: That fixed the problem, but it seems that this method causes the sheet to constantly blink.  Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Does "SampleChange" contain code that changes "K1", if so you'll get into a loop where K1 is changed, then the change event causes this subroutine to fire, which changes K1, which causes the subroutine to fire, etc, etc.

Comment: I must have something like that going on.  I'll check my samplechange code and see if that is the case.  Thank you for your help